# Django: how to redirect test_func to 403 forbidden page instead of login

Tags: django, redirect, django-class-based-views

When a logged in user wants to update a post (UpdateView) he has not created, the test_func function should redirect the user to the 403 Forbidden page instead of the login page. However in my case, it redirects to the login page even if the user is already logged in. Does anybody has an idea of why it is happening ? Thank you!﻿

```
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
model = Post
fields = ['title', 'content']

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    return super(PostUpdateView,self).form_valid(form)

def test_func(self):
    post = self.get_object()
    if self.request.user == post.author:
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    raise_exception = True  # <<<---
    ...
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin

Comment: Thank you! It works but it does not do exactly what I was looking for.

What I want :
Not logged in users --> redirect to login page.
Logged in users but not the author of the post --> 403 forbidden.

What your code does:
Both case --> 403 forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried PermissionDenied from django.core.exceptions?

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

def edit(request, pk):
    if not request.user.is_staff:
        raise PermissionDenied
    # ...
```

You could do something like this:

```
def test_func(self):
    post = self.get_object()
    if self.request.user == post.author:
        return True
    raise PermissionDenied
```